# Simulation-based power analysis for Linear Mixed Model (repeated measures) using pilot data

Tags: r, simulation, lme4, mixed-models

I am doing a simple mixed model analysis and would like to estimate the power of the study (for multiple possible sample sizes). I am using `lme4` to fit the models and would like to use the `simulate()` function in order to simulate new data based on the parameters estimated in my pilot study model and then to use this data for power analysis.

My model is:

```
m.2 <- lmer(y ~ time + group + (time | subject), REML=FALSE)
```

And the data looks like this:

```
npg <- 20 # No of subjects per group
subject <- 1:(2*npg) # Subjects' ids
group <- gl(2, npg, labels = c("Control", "Treatment"))
dts <- data.frame(subject, group) # Subject-level data
dtL <- list(time = 0:9,
       subject = subject)
dtLong <- expand.grid(dtL) # "Long" format
mrgDt <- merge(dtLong, dts, sort = FALSE) # Merged
```

I know I can get the parameters from the pilot data model like this:

```
newparams <- list(
  beta = fixef(m.2),
  theta = getME(m.2, "theta"),
  sigma = getME(m.2, "sigma"))
```

And that I can simulate new data using this:

```
ss <- simulate(~ time + group + (time|subject),
               nsim=1,
               newdata=d,
               family=gaussian,
               newparams=newparams)
```

Unfortunately, I'm new to simulation and don't really know how to do power analysis with simulated data sets. Could you help me with some code and some advice?

EDIT:

I would like to do a power analysis similar to the one in Gałecki & Burzykowski (2013) book.

Gałecki, A., & Burzykowski, T. (2013). Linear mixed-effects models using R: A step-by-step approach. Springer Science & Business Media, p. 515. The example is: Empirical power of the F-test for the treatment effect based on the simulated values of the F-test statistics.

The info in https://peerj.com/articles/1226.pdf and the Supplemental Information (https://peerj.com/articles/1226/#supp-1) is very useful and I think it's the way to go, but I don't understand how to apply their code.

I wanted to simulate data based on the real parameters of the fitted model from my pilot study. 
I don't have all the data ready at the current time.For the sake of example and reproducibility let's say I use the plantgrowth data set

```
df<-read.table('http://www.uib.no/People/nzlkj/statkey/data/plantgrowth.csv',header=T)
```

and my model is

```
m.2 <- lmer(height ~ time + treat + (time | individual), REML=FALSE)
```

Under my control is the number of individuals in each arm or the study (the two groups, treatment and control).

Comment: Your question needs some clarification/a reproducible example (i.e., what are the values of `newparams` from your pilot study? (1) What aspects of the experiment are under your control? i.e., can you increase the number of groups, or the number of time points, or the strength of the effect?  Or do you just want a single number (power) for your full study size?  (2) You might look at http://rpubs.com/bbolker/11703, http://rpubs.com/bbolker/3324, http://rpubs.com/bbolker/zinb_power , https://peerj.com/articles/1226.pdf, https://peerj.com/articles/1226/Supplement_1_Kain_Bolker_McCoy.pdf ...

Comment: The new `simr` package will handle a lot of the difficult parts of simulation-based power for you. The [version on GitHub](https://github.com/pitakakariki/simr/), which you can install with `devtools::install_github()` has several improvements not yet available on CRAN.